# How is MySQL interpreting: ORDER BY CASE status WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE -1 END DESC

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working on an existing project and found this SQL statement. After reviewing the [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html), I'm a still confused by the syntax and how MySQL is interpreting it.

I have a column called `status` that can be 0 (inactive), 1 (active), 2 (completed), 3 (testing).

`ORDER BY CASE status WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE -1 END DESC, id ASC`

What confuses me is `THEN 1 ELSE -1`. In the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html) it mentions that you place a `statement_list` after `THEN`. I would expect to see something like this:

`ORDER BY CASE status WHEN 1 THEN status ELSE -1 (or some other value that will be ignored) END DESC, id ASC`

How is mysql interpreting `THEN 1 ELSE -1`? I guess I'm curious how this statement is returning the right results. It is basically doing this: If status = 1 then `ORDER BY status DESC` else ignore the order by statement.

Comment: will put all the status =1 before status=all others.So when status =1 it ORDERs BY 1 if status !=1 it ORDERs BY -1.Since it is DESC status=1 comes before status = -1

Comment: `statement_list` is actually missleading as list implies multiple *whatever*, but it's only one...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ORDER BY CASE status WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE -1 END DESC, id ASC

This means it'll order by (1 or -1 DESC, id ASC) effectively.

Based on the value of status it'll put a 1 or -1 as the first expression to order by and "id ASC" is the tie breaker. Rows with `status = 1` will come first in the result (ordered by `id` in ascending order) and rows with other values for `status` will be returned after that (their order is not specified any further).

Comment: You said "Based on the value of status it'll put a 1 or -1 as the first expression to order by" But what column is that ordering by? I assume it is ordering by "status" but I would really like to see some documentation that shows the different ways I can use this statement. I feel like im just guessing its results right now.

Comment: @zechdc: it's ordering by the value of 1 or -1. It's not ordering by status but it's using the value of status to determine whether a 1 or -1 should be used. This means you've got some control over how the rows are ordered but it's really Mysql deciding in what order to return the rows (because it's only sorting by 1 or -1 in descending order).

Comment: What does ordering by 1 or -1 do then? Does mysql just randomly choose a column and sort it DESC?

Comment: @zechdc: the column itself contains only 1 or -1 values. So those are the values that get sorted in descending order. You don't have control over how rows with the same value get sorted (i.e., Mysql decides how to order the rows that all have the value 1 and how to order the rows that all have the value -1). The only guarantee is that this column with 1 and -1 values gets sorted in descending order.

Answer (score 0):

It would order by active status first (1) because of the `DESC` clause, then everything else would be returned after that.  Anything assigned -1 may be randomly ordered.